# Icecast different logins for same mountpoint

Tags: authentication, icecast

Hello StackOverflow Users,
I have an icecast 2 server with a few mountpoints.

Now I have one mountpoint for guests.
But every guest has the same user:pass login, whitch I set in the icecast config.

Is it possible to create a new user:pass login for a guest at runtime?
I think with a mysql database it is possible, but I found nothing for icecast.

Here a little example.
A guest ask me, if he could stream a session on my icecast stream.
I create a new user:pass for the guest mountpoint, send the credentials to this guest and he can stream.
But I don't need to restart the hole icecast server to make the new user:pass combi work.

Answer (score 0):

Offload source authentication to an authentication back-end of your choice.
Relevant documentation: http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#source-auth

Also note that you don't need to restart Icecast for configuration changes to take effect. A simple *SIGHUP* will make it reread and apply configuration. (Not supported on Windows until 2.5 gets released)